# Grooviest way to store a BLOB in a database?

Tags: java, database, groovy, blob

While writing a utility script to insert images into a database I wondered if there were a groovier way of doing it. In the end settled for something along the lines of this:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(...)
// ...    
Connection conn = sql.getConnection()
PreparedStatement stmt.prepareStatment(...)
stmt.setBinary(...)
stmt.executeUpate()
```

There must be a groovier way, can someone enlighten me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'groovier'?

Comment: I avoid storing images in the database as it takes up a lot of space, they are slow to retrieve, and can't be indexed or searched usefully. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Absolutely not but it's something I have to live with!

Comment: I thought there may be a better way to achieve this using a Groovy idiom.

Answer (score 2):

A "Groovier" way could be just storing the path were you'd store the images.

Storing the images in a directory and storing just the path in the db is the best way.